# Resonant peak frequencies for phaser effect

Tags: sound, allpass

I have a [conventional phaser setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaser_%28effect%29) with allpass filters and feedback.

I can calculate the peaks frequencies of the phaser when the allpass delays are set to 1 (then they work as simple one sample delays). Adding two allpass delays will give an additional peak, and the peak frequencies for peaks i = 1 to N is found by:

```
(i / (N + 0.5) ) * SampleRate / 2
```

where N is the number of peaks (and the number of allpass-delays divided by 2).
So if you have a 6-stage phaser at 44100, the 3 peaks will be at:

```
(1 / (3 + 0.5) ) * 44100 / 2 = 6300
(2 / (3 + 0.5) ) * 44100 / 2 = 12600
(3 / (3 + 0.5) ) * 44100 / 2 = 18900
```

However, these frequencies start warping when the allpass-delays are not set to 1:

[image: Phaser using 8 allpass filters]

How can I calculate the peak frequencies when the allpass-delays are not set to 1?

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the following structure of a phaser (from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaser_%28effect%29)):

[image]

Let's call the depth factor $a$, and the feedback factor $f$ ($|f|<1$).
I assume that there are $2N$ first order allpass filters, each with transfer function

$$A_0(z)=\frac{z^{-1}-b}{1-bz^{-1}},\quad |b|<1\tag{1}$$

The allpass frequency response is obtained by evaluating (1) on the unit circle $z=e^{j\omega}$:

$$A_0(e^{j\omega})=\frac{e^{-j\omega}-b}{1-be^{-j\omega}}=
\frac{e^{-j\omega}-2b+b^2e^{j\omega}}{|1-be^{-j\omega}|^2}=\\
=\frac{(1+b^2)\cos(\omega)-2b+j(b^2-1)\sin(\omega)}{|1-be^{-j\omega}|^2}\tag{2}$$

And since $A_0(z)$ is an allpass function

$$A_0(e^{j\omega})=e^{j\phi(\omega)}\tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3) the phase $\phi(\omega)$ of the allpass satisfies

$$\tan(\phi(\omega))=\frac{(b^2-1)\sin(\omega)}{(1+b^2)\cos(\omega)-2b}\tag{4}$$

If you cascade $2N$ of these allpass filters, the frequency response of this cascade is

$$[A_0(e^{j\omega})]^{2N}=e^{j2N\phi(\omega)}$$

Let us first consider a system without feedback, i.e. $f=0$. The total frequency response of such a system is

$$H(e^{j\omega})=1+ae^{j2N\phi(\omega)}=
1+a\cos(2N\phi(\omega))+ja\sin(2N\phi(\omega))$$

and its squared magnitude is

$$|H(e^{j\omega})|^2=1+2a\cos(2N\phi(\omega))+a^2\tag{5}$$

From (5) it is obvious that the locations of the maxima of $|H(e^{j\omega})|^2$ are independent of the depth paramter $a$, and that they only depend on $N$ and on the allpass phase response $\phi(\omega)$ (i.e. on the paramter $b$). The maxima occur where the argument of the cosine in (5) equals $2\pi k$, $k=0,1,\ldots,N$, which is equivalent to

$$\phi(\omega_k)=\frac{k\pi}{N},\quad k=0,1,\ldots,N$$

where $\omega_k$ are the peak frequencies. With (4) this condition becomes

$$\frac{(b^2-1)\sin(\omega_k)}{(1+b^2)\cos(\omega_k)-2b}=\tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{N}\right),\quad k=0,1,\ldots,N\tag{6}$$

Equation (6) can be used to determine the peak frequencies $\omega_k$. Note that this needs to be done numerically since this equation cannot be solved for $\omega_k$ analytically. There are just some special indices $k$ for which an explicit solution is possible:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\omega_0&=&0\\
\omega_{N/2}&=&\arccos\left(\frac{2b}{1+b^2}\right)\quad\textrm{if } N \textrm{ is even}\\
\omega_N&=&\pi
\end{array}$$

The following figure is an example for $N=4$, $a=0.7$, and $b=0.6$ which shows $|H(e^{j\omega})|$
and the locations of the maxima (shown by 'x') which I've computed using equation (4).

[image]

If there is feedback ($f\neq 0$) then the frequency response looks more complicated:

$$H(e^{j\omega})=\frac{1+(a-f)e^{j2N\phi(\omega)}}{1-fe^{j2N\phi(\omega)}}$$

and its squared magnitude is

$$|H(e^{j\omega})|^2=\frac{1+2(a-f)\cos(2N\phi(\omega))+(a-f)^2}{1-2f\cos(2N\phi(\omega))+f^2}$$

Luckily it turns out that feedback doesn't change the location of the peaks, it just makes them 'peakier'. In the following figure the system the frequency response shown above is compared to the response with feedback ($f=0.5$):

[image]

Comment: Hmm, the number of allpass filters seem to be missing from this formula, (or maybe I am missing something)?

The formula has a linear relationship between peak index (k) and frequency, but as soon as the delays are not 1 the peaks starts warping non-linearly, this is also what gives the phaser its characteristic sound. (I added an image that might help make things clearer)

Comment: @teadrinker I used $D$ as the delay which can be fractional, irrespective of the number of allpass filters realizing the delay. What do you mean by "as soon as the delays are not 1"? What are they then? If you have general allpass filters with a non-linear phase response then you must specify the behavior of these allpass filters, otherwise nothing can be said about the peak frequencies.

Comment: I based my experiments on the code snippets of 
[these comments](http://www.musicdsp.org/showArchiveComment.php?ArchiveID=78). The allpass process function does:
`Result := inSample * -Fa1 + Fzm1;`
`Fzm1 := Result * Fa1 + inSample`. And Fa1 is `(1 - delay) / (1 + delay)`

Comment: @teadrinker OK, so you have $2N$ of these first order allpass filters in series. Do they all use the same parameter Fa1?

Comment: Correct, they all use the same Fa1.

Comment: @teadrinker I finally had the time to discuss the general allpass case and edited my answer accordingly. Please have a look.

Comment: It's not easy for me to wrap my head around this math, but b is the delay, right? It looks like our formulas and code does not match up, when I plug in b = 0.6 for N=4 (8 allpass filters, each using delay 0.6), I get the peaks around 0, 0.45, 0.98, 1.68, 2.6. I also noticed that with your formulas you get a peak at nyquist, this only happens in my case when using negative feedback or odd number of allpass filters.

Comment: I cleaned up and rebuilt an [example](http://goo.gl/4nDwcN), including a approximation (which is only really correct at b == 1, but kind of aligns until 0.5), note that this webapp might be slow, since it is calculating the sound and 5 spectrograms in javascript.

Comment: @teadrinker $b$ is what's called 'Fa1' in your code. Just to be sure: you add the direct signal and a cascade of $2N$ identical allpass filters (ignoring feedback for the moment), right? For this case, the formula should be correct. But somehow I start thinking that we might be talking about different structures ... need to clear this up.

Comment: $b$ is what you called 'k' in your webapp.

Comment: @teadrinker Check out this figure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phaser_response.png Here $N=4$ (8 stages) and there are also peaks at 0 and at Nyquist.

Comment: Right, b is k, that makes much more sense. You are right, there IS a maxima at nyquist. I think I found mismatch, I added the depth (a) to the example and it seems like the feedbackpeaks surprisingly [does not align with the maxima](http://goo.gl/GKAkUz).

Comment: @teadrinker From my experiments it appears that feedback does not change the location of the maxima. I've added a figure to my answer. By the way, were you maybe talking about *notch* frequencies instead of peak frequencies, i.e. frequency where the attenuation is maximum? I've check everything and I'm pretty sure that everything is correct now, at least according to the phaser structure from wikipedia. Do we at least get the same results without feedback?

Comment: Interesting, no I am talking about notch (and by the way, they are also not aligned). But I _did_ managed to get the responses to align for the case b=1, by adding an additional allpass _outside_ the feedback loop. I am not sure I got the explaination right, but isnt it that implementing feedback in a straight forward way in the digital domain will give you an additional 1 sample delay in the feedback loop.

Comment: @teadrinker: If you use $b$ the same way as I use $b$, then $b=1$ doesn't make sense because then each allpass becomes a simple inverter (check Eq. (1) of my answer, $A_0(z)=-1$), and $2N$ cascaded allpass filters are just a straight connection without any processing. Furthermore, there is no delay in the feedback loop. Imagine a trivial system $y(n)=ax(n)$. Now add a feedback term (with factor $f$) without delay: $y(n)=a(x(n)+fy(n))\Rightarrow y(n)=ax(n)/(1-af)$, so it can be done. Honestly, I'm pretty sure that your implementation does not agree with the system I've analyzed.